# Selenium Python Pass Date parameter using Calendar

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am trying to pull data from following page:

```
https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/ListOfFundNAVs
```

I have to select the name of the company and select a date from the calendar and click get data button.
I am trying to achieve this using Selenium Web Driver using Chrome in Python, I am stuck how do i pass the date parameter to the page.
it seems the page is postback after selection of date from the calendar.
Date needs to be selected from the calendar else the data is not returned by the webpage.
I have tried using requests Post method as well but am not able to get the NAV data.

I need to iterate this for a period of 5 years on daily (Trading Days) basis.

PS: I am bad at understanding DOM elements and have basic knowledge of Python and coding. by profession I am a data analyst.

Thanks in Advance.
Kiran Jain

edit: adding current code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/ListOfFundNAVs'

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
# opt.add_argument("--headless")
opt.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
driver.get('https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/ListOfFundNAVs');
insurer = driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_drpselectinscompany")
nav_date=driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_txtdateselect')
get_data_btn=driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_btngetdetails')

options=insurer.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
data=[]
row={'FirmName','SFIN','fundName','NAVDate','NAV'}
for option in options:
    print('here')
    print(option.get_attribute("value") + ' ' + option.text)
   
    if(option.text!='--Select Insurer--'):
        option.click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_imgbtncalender").click()#Calender Icon
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("June").click()#Date
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("25").click()#Date
        get_data_btn=driver.find_element_by_id('MainContent_btngetdetails') #this is put here again because on clicking the date, the page is reloaded
        get_data_btn.click()
        print('clicked')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is there any code that you have tried?

Comment: added code but this is not working gives error while looping back to second element after the click, 
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException
Message: stale element reference:

The selected date is just a sample - i would need to loop thru all the dates from 01 Jan 2016 till today - These dates can be passed as parameter to an exe which will be generated thru batch file (to pass only traded dates as parameters) or will build some more error checks / try catch types which will take care of non trading days

Comment: I am now trying to fetch data using POST method. but i am stuck as the viewstate keeps changing with every parameter selected on the website.
Below is the post which have asked separately.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388379/unable-to-fetch-data-from-lifeinsurancecouncil-using-requests-post-method

Answer (score 1):

The date is in "a" tag. You can try to do select the date using "link-text".

```
    driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_imgbtncalender").click()#Calender Icon
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("27").click()#Date
```

As per your comment I tried to traverse through dates but it only worked for that particular month. I tried to use "send_keys()" to that text box and its not working. Below is the code to traverse it for a month.

```
driver.get("https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/ListOfFundNAVs")
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_drpselectinscompany").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[starts-with(text(),'Aditya')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_imgbtncalender").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("1").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_btngetdetails").click()
dateval = 2

while True:
    if dateval == 32:
        break
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_imgbtncalender").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(dateval)).click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_btngetdetails").click()
        dateval+=1
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        dateval+=1
        time.sleep(2)

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks but i need data for 5 years, every time the date is clicked, it seems the page is reloaded and the next time we click on the calendar, it starts from the beginning.

Comment: The Website gives option to select one date. I think If it had options like from date and to date options, it would have been possible.